# How get project parent directory in pom.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml

In maven set path to chrome driver as:

```
<driver.chrome>${project.basedir}/../repo</driver.chrome>
```

As result path is: `D:\MyProj\..\repo`

Answer: `driver.chrome>file://${project.basedir}\..\repo</driver.chrome>`

Comment: Please, if you are asking for help, kindly honour us with an actual question.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I understand what you're asking. The resulting path you're getting is not minimized, but as far as I know, it is a valid path and it would work on any operating system.

In other words - `D:\MyProj\..\repo` is valid and equivalent to `D:\repo`. Go ahead and try to paste it into Windows Explorer and see if it opens it. Or `cd` to it in command prompt.

Comment: It works for Windows Explorer, but not in maven pom.xml